# Is there a way to make text italic with Python-Fu for GIMP?

Tags: gimp, gimpfu, python-fu

My script changes text in a text layer, but doing that changes the text from italic to normal text. Is there a way to not make it change; or to change it back afterwards?

I looked in the command browser in gimp but only found commands to change the font itself. I couldn't find a way to pass any additional formatting, but maybe I missed something.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Gimp has no notion of "Italic" or "Bold" font attributes. Fonts usually have several variants that appear "italic" (such as `Latin Modern Sans Oblique` or  `Latin Modern Roman Slanted`) or "bold" with various degrees (`Noto Sans` goes form `Noto Sans Thin` to `Noto Sans Heavy`, with intermediate `Semi-bold`,`Bold`, and `Ultra-bold` variants. But it's all in the name.